# Why is it "um" in this sentence and not "für"?

Tags: preposition

*Da kommen die Eltern, um ihre Kinder abzuholen.*

I've researched a bit [here](https://www.thoughtco.com/difference-between-fur-and-for-1444433) but still couldn't get how the um is used in this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Um' in this context means 'in order to'. 'Um etwas zu tun' is a standard formulation in German.
'Für' is not used in that sense